# When should we put a comma before "but"?

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation, commas

I think the word "but" is a conjunction. Can someone explain me when in English we put a comma before it and in what cases we do not do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma must be used before "but" when this word is separating two independent clauses. For example:

"I like sunny days, but Carla prefers the rain."

In this case "*I like sunny days*" and "*Carla prefers the rain*" are two valid, therefore independent, sentences. For this reason you must use a comma before the word "but".

Now look at this other sentence:

"I like sunny days but Carla, the rainy ones."

Notice that "*Carla, the rainy ones*" is not a valid and independent clause, it depends on the first clause to make sense, so no comma is used before the word "but".

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. I noticed your comma before "the rainy ones" in the second sentence. Earlier it was strange to me, but now I got used to such commas. In Russian we mostly use dashes in such cases.